# Extract vectors from strsplit list without using a loop

Tags: r

Considering the following vector:

```
[1] "1-1694429" "2-1546669" "3-928598"  "4-834486"  "5-802353"  "6-659439"  "7-552850" 
"8-516804"  "9-364061" 
[10] "10-354181" "11-335154" "12-257915" "13-251310" "14-232313" "15-217628" "16-216569"
```

I am trying to generate two vectors, each of them containing the values obtained by splitting each element of the vector by the delimiter "-".

I used:

```
f <- function(s) strsplit(s, "-")
cc<-sapply(names.reads, f)
```

> head(cc)
>       $`1-1694429`
>       [1] "1"       "1694429"

```
$`2-1546669`

[1] "2"       "1546669"
```

I know I can access them like:

```
> cc[[1]][1]
[1] "1"

> cc[[1]][2]
[1] "1694429"
```

I would like to have two vectors , each one containing the values stored at  `cc[[i]][1]` and `cc[[i]][2]`...Can I do that without using a loop? (I have over 1 million elements )

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "select separately without using a loop" - you'll have to do cc[[i]] for the i'th vector...do you mean you just want a flat vector with all the string bits in it? (by the way, you can do `cc <- strsplit(names.reads,'-')` without having to use `sapply`.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee I have edited my question, I hope it's a bit more clear ..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using mathematical.coffee's suggestion, the following code avoids loops or `sapply`

```
names.reads <- c("1-1694429", "2-1546669", "3-928598", "4-834486", "5-802353",
              "6-659439",  "7-552850",  "8-516804", "9-364061", "10-354181",
              "11-335154", "12-257915", "13-251310", "14-232313", "15-217628",
              "16-216569")

cc       <- strsplit(names.reads,'-')
part1    <- unlist(cc)[2*(1:length(names.reads))-1]
part2    <- unlist(cc)[2*(1:length(names.reads))  ]
```

produces

```
> part1
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15"
[16] "16"
> part2
 [1] "1694429" "1546669" "928598"  "834486"  "802353"  "659439"  "552850" 
 [8] "516804"  "364061"  "354181"  "335154"  "257915"  "251310"  "232313" 
[15] "217628"  "216569"
```

though it does require each original value to be in the expected format.

Comment: I am accepting your answer, because sapply failed at less than a quarter of the size of my vector (always like that with sapply for some reason)and your nice solution suits me better.

Comment: It is the faster one, but the problem with this solution is that all elements must be of the form: `x_xxxxx` once you have mission one of the value, it doesn't work well, for example: `1694429` instead of: `1-1694429`. The `strsplit` for such cases only generates a list with one value, not the pair of value. Then the calculation of selecting even and odd index does not work. The solution pointed by @MYaseen208 is the one with less performance but it covers this case.

Answer (score 10):

Using `sapply()` (for completeness' sake):

`y <- c("1-1694429", "2-1546669", "3-928598",  "4-834486",  "5-802353",  "6-659439",  "7-552850", "8-516804",  "9-364061",
"10-354181", "11-335154", "12-257915", "13-251310", "14-232313", "15-217628", "16-216569")`

As @Bird pointed out in the comments, the `USE.NAMES` parameter can be used to avoid names in the resulting vector.

`x <- sapply(y, function(x) strsplit(x, "-")[[1]], USE.NAMES=FALSE)`

`a <- x[1,]`

`b <- x[2,]`

Comment: this solution splits it twice. computationaly expensive

Comment: The `USE.NAMES=FALSE` option in `sappaly()` also removes the names.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach:

```
names.reads <- c("1-1694429", "2-1546669", "3-928598", "4-834486", "5-802353",
              "6-659439",  "7-552850",  "8-516804", "9-364061", "10-354181",
              "11-335154", "12-257915", "13-251310", "14-232313", "15-217628",
              "16-216569")

library(reshape2)
colsplit(string=names.reads, pattern="-", names=c("Part1", "Part2"))

   Part1   Part2
1      1 1694429
2      2 1546669
3      3  928598
4      4  834486
5      5  802353
6      6  659439
7      7  552850
8      8  516804
9      9  364061
10    10  354181
11    11  335154
12    12  257915
13    13  251310
14    14  232313
15    15  217628
16    16  216569
```

Comment: This solution also works for non-uniform data. For example if you have '1-2-3' and 1-2' you will end up with an array of 1 and 1, and an array of 2-3 and 2. It worked for my application of getting the top level directory name of all directories within a directory. (actually, an S3 bucket via aws.s3)

Answer (score 5):

Or with the `purrr` package:

Part 1:

```
> map(strsplit(names.reads, "-"), ~.x[1]) %>% unlist()
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13"
[14] "14" "15" "16"
```

Part 2:

```
> map(strsplit(names.reads, "-"), ~.x[2]) %>% unlist()
[1] "1694429" "1546669" "928598"  "834486"  "802353"  "659439" 
[7] "552850"  "516804"  "364061"  "354181"  "335154"  "257915" 
[13] "251310"  "232313"  "217628"  "216569"
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking to solve a similar problem, came across this post. Adding my solution to this though I am far ahead in the future! (copying from Henry the code)

```
names.reads <- c("1-1694429", "2-1546669", "3-928598", "4-834486", "5-802353",
          "6-659439",  "7-552850",  "8-516804", "9-364061", "10-354181",
          "11-335154", "12-257915", "13-251310", "14-232313", "15-217628",
          "16-216569")

require(plyr)
cc <- ldply(strsplit(names.reads, '-'))
cc$V1;cc$V2
```

That produces a data frame from which the vectors pertaining to the nth element of each item in the list can be extracted.